# Get Binding from a FrameworkElementFactory

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, frameworkelementfactory

In a GirdView the text of some columns sould be aligned to the right.
To do that I create a DataTemplate, which contains a TextBlock.

```
Binding bd = new Binding("path");

FrameworkElementFactory tbContent = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(TextBlock));
tbContent.SetBinding(TextBlock.TextProperty, bd);
tbContent.SetValue(TextBlock.TextAlignmentProperty, TextAlignment.Right);

DataTemplate dataTemplate = new DataTemplate();
dataTemplate.VisualTree = tbContent;

myGridViewColumn.CellTemplate = dataTemplate;
```

In an other class I have to access the Bindings of my GridViewColumns. How can I access the Binding of this column?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, so I exposed the TextAlignmentProperty as a public property.